# Cloudfront cachea web de s3

Tags: aws

Tengo una web estática en un bucket s3 de AWS, enlazada con cloudfront.

El problema es que al modificar el index.html y las carpetas de css y js, al refrescar no carga el nuevo contenido, aparece el antiguo.

He probado a poner las TTL a 0, a cambiar la url en el cloudfront y nada.

Entrando por la url que da S3 funciona todo ok, pero con el dominio no.

Esta es la configuración: `CNAME : xxx.cloudfront.net`

apunte `A : ALIAS xxx.cloudfront.net.`

Algún consejo? Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque ese es el comportamiento esperado de CloudFront, tienes dos opciones.

#### Invalidaciones

Si necesitas eliminar un objeto del caché antes de que expire, puedes **invalidarlo**, de este modo, cuando un cliente solicite ese objeto, se llamará desde el *bucket* S3.

Puedes invalidar un objeto, un tipo de objeto (`*.jpg`) o un directorio (`imágenes/*`). Para hacerlo tienes que ir a tu distribución de CloudFront donde verás la pestaña de Invaldaciones y el botón para crearlas.
[[image: Pestaña Invalidar]

El cuadro de diálogo que aparece se explica por si solo:
[image: Cuadro de Diálogo «Invalidar»]

#### Versionado

Puedes crear un objeto en tu bucket y agregarle al nombre una característica distintiva. Lo más común es un *timestamp*:

```
imagen-201703091756.jpg
```

De este modo cuando solicites esa versión, CloudFront la llamará desde el bucket.

La ventaja de esta opción es que puedes hacer programáticamente con el lenguaje de tu elección.

> En la documentación de [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) encontrarás más información.

PD. **Eliminé la etiqueta [dns](/questions/tagged/dns) porque no es relevante para tu pregunta**.

Comment: Genial! Ese era el problema